# Finding a specific bound using Cauchy's integral formula

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

Let $f\in\mathcal{H}(\mathbb{D})$ and $\alpha>0$ a real value so that there exists $c>0$ such that for any $|z|<1$, $(1-|z|)^\alpha|f(z)|\leq c$. I have to show that $|f^{(n)}(0)|\leq cn!(e/\alpha)^\alpha(n+\alpha)^\alpha$.

By now I have applied Cauchy's integral formula in order to get that, for any $0<r<1$,
$$|f^{(n)}(0)|\leq \frac{n!}{r^n}\sup_{|z|=r}|f(z)|\leq \frac{cn!}{r^n(1-r)^\alpha}.$$
After that, I have found the minimum bound, minimizing $g(r):=\frac{cn!}{r^n(1-r)^\alpha}$ for $0<r<1$, getting $r=\frac{n}{\alpha+n}$.

The problem is that once I substitute that value of $r$ in the function, I do not obtain the bound I am supposed to get and also I do not know how to bound this
$$|f^{(n)}(0)|\leq cn!(n+\alpha)^\alpha\frac{(n+\alpha)^n}{n^{n+\alpha}}.$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error in your last inequality.
Substituting $r=\frac{n}{\alpha+n}$ in $\frac{cn!}{r^n(1-r)^\alpha}$
gives
$$
 |f^{(n)}(0)|\le \frac{c n! (n+\alpha)^n (n+\alpha)^\alpha}{n^n \alpha^\alpha} 
= \frac{c n!  (n+\alpha)^\alpha}{ \alpha^\alpha} \bigl( 1+\frac{\alpha}{n} \bigr)^n
$$
and it remains to show that
$$
 \bigl( 1+\frac{\alpha}{n} \bigr)^n = \left( \bigl( 1+\frac{\alpha}{n} \bigr)^\frac{n}{\alpha} \right)^\alpha < e^\alpha
$$
which follows from
$$
 \bigl( 1 + \frac 1x \bigr)^x < e \text{ for } x > 0 \, .
$$

Comment: Ah yes I see! Thank you very much.